# How to generate a random number in substrate?

Tags: substrate

Hi guys is it possible to generate a random number in substrate using the rand crate?

because as soon as I import it into my Cargo.toml file

```
[dependencies.rand] 
version = '0.7.3'
```

it gives me the following error

```
duplicate lang item in crate `std` (which `rand` depends on): `panic_impl`.
  |
  = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
  = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/noone/powattem/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-335dca76a9d63bdd.rmeta
  = note: second definition in `std` loaded from /home/noone/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-023ef8617de52e0e.rlib
```

Answer (score 2):

The node template includes [the Randomness Collective Flip pallet](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0-rc5/pallet_randomness_collective_flip/), which implements [the Randomness trait](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0-rc5/frame_support/traits/trait.Randomness.html). It looks like the crate you are trying to import has `std` dependencies, which will not work in a Substrate runtime that must compiled to Wasm.